# How did this person get this number for calculating planetary energy budget formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the problem, I keep getting it like this:
$\sqrt[4]{\frac{1370\left(1-0.3\right)-4.367}{\left(5.67\cdot 10^{-8}\right)}}
= 360.21$

How does this person get the value 256.155K?

[image]

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: You seem to have a $-$ sign where the image has a $+$ sign.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank. Still not 256.155K. Wondering how this person got this answer.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\sqrt[4]{\frac{1370\left(1-0.3\right)-4.367}{\left(5.67\cdot 10^{-8}\right)}}
&= 360.21 \\
\sqrt[4]{\frac{1370\left(1-0.3\right)+4.367}{\left(5.67\cdot 10^{-8}\right)}}
&= 361.04 \qquad (2\, \text{dp})
\end{align}

Not really sure sure what's going on....

Comment: Maybe the teacher made a mistake?

Comment: @yre That happens (I know from experience). Ask.

Comment: @EthanBolker cool. Thanks. Just wanted to do a sanity check on this first and make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: @yre Yes I believe that that could be the answer.